# Unable to build parity from source on macOS

Tags: parity, mac-osx, build-from-source

Just did a fresh clone from github and:

```
cargo build --release --features final
```

gives me a link error:

```
  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "_je_malloc_usable_size", referenced from:
                heapsize::heap_size_of_impl::hc4000c6f954eaceb in libheapsize-95360de80c444e06.rlib(heapsize-95360de80c444e06.heapsize.68twyoht-cgu.1.rcgu.o)
                _$LT$alloc..string..String$u20$as$u20$heapsize..HeapSizeOf$GT$::heap_size_of_children::haf2fa16c6b4e920b in libheapsize-95360de80c444e06.rlib(heapsize-95360de80c444e06.heapsize.68twyoht-cgu.4.rcgu.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `parity-ethereum`.
```

My config is:

```
rustc 1.32.0
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
```

Is there a workaround for this link error?

Comment: This is a known issue and there's a workaround in this PR https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/pull/10234 that might help until we get the actual issue resolved

Comment: @Joshua Mir, thanks for pointing me to this PR! Will test it asap. Could you put your comment as an answer so I can vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: there is a [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/pull/10234) that acts as a temporary fix for this issue.